# Combining manipulated plots

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Let's say I have two manipulated plots:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}], {a, 0, 10}]
Manipulate[Plot[Cos[b x], {x, 0, Pi}], {b, 0, 10}]
```

How can I create a new plot that combines these two and is updated dynamically by each of them? Can I somehow use `Show[]`?

Of course I could create a unified manipulator, but in reality these are a handful of conceptually separate problems with lots of sliders each and I'd hate to duplicate them all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does what you want.

```
Manipulate[plots = Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}], {a, 0, 10}] 
Manipulate[plotc = Plot[Cos[b x], {x, 0, Pi}], {b, 0, 10}]
Show[plots, plotc] // Dynamic
```

Comment: OK good. Although `Row[]` seems a bit redundant here. :)

Comment: Good point - I've edited out the `Row`.

Comment: Stripping off the braces too might leave on only the necessary. :P

Comment: Braces stripped, and the comma as well!

Answer (score 5):

The question is not very clearly posed but may be `Panel` is what you are looking for.

```
Panel[Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}], {{a, 2}, 0, 10}]
      Manipulate[Plot[Cos[b x], {x, 0, Pi}], {{b, 2}, 0, 10}], 
      FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]