# How to transform a DynamicModule into a Graphic

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I am generating a graph through a custom function using `DynamicModule`:

```
graph1 = customFunction[a]
```

If I try to do:

```
Show[graph1]
```

I get the message

> "DynamicModule is not a type of graphics."

How can I convert the output of my `DynamicModule` function into a graphic? My ultimate goal is to combine multiple graphics with `Show`:

```
graph1 = customFunction[a]
graph2 = customFunction[b]  
Show[graph1,graph2]
```

Comment: It is the [same as here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13461/5478) exept that You have `DynamicModule`s not `Manipulate`s.

Comment: OK thanks so what it means is that I have to pass the name of the graph I want to plot to my customFunction and then plot the graph inside this variable.

Comment: No, You only have to assign graphics object inside Your `DynamicModule` to variable, and then `Show` it outsiede, like in the link. Well, I can not guess more without any insight into Your code.

Answer (score 2):

Following up Kuba's comment:

```
  DynamicModule[{a}, Row[
  {
   Column[
    {
     Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 5}, Appearance -> "Labeled"],
     Dynamic[plot1 = Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
        PlotRange -> {-\[Pi], \[Pi]},
        Background -> LightBlue,
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        ImageSize -> 250]]
     }],
   Column[
    {
     Slider[Dynamic[b], {-5, 5}, Appearance -> "Labeled"],
     Dynamic[plot2 = Plot[Tan[b x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
        PlotRange -> {-\[Pi], \[Pi]},
        Background -> LightGreen,
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        ImageSize -> 250]]
     }]
   }, " "
  ]]
```

[image: plots]

```
Show[plot1, plot2, Background -> LightPurple] // Dynamic
```

[image: combined]

The bottom graphic updates as you adjust the sliders. I had to mix the Blue and Green backgrounds manually, of course...:)