# Combine a dynamic module with a manipulation

Tags: plotting, dynamic, manipulate, interactive

I would like to combine a dynamic module with a manipulation, whilst maintaining the functionality of both. I have tried things like `Show` and `Epilog -> Inset@...`, but neither seem to work. The code for both dynamic module & manipulation are as follows:

```
Manipulate[
Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, GridLines -> {Range@5, Range@5}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
PlotStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 200], {n, -3, 3},

DynamicModule[{x = 11}, Grid[Map[Button[ToString@#, x = #, Background -> 
Dynamic[If[Divisible[#, x], Green, Red]], ImageSize -> {40, 40}, Appearance -> 
"Frameless"] &, RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 5}], {2}], Frame -> All, 
FrameStyle -> Dashed, Spacings -> {.2, .2}]]]
```

produces:

[image]

Functionality in the above illustration is preserved, but I would really like one to overlay the other (plot on top 'layer'). I have included the grid on both to show how I would like to align them.

I have looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/moving-from-dynamic-module-to-manipulate), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13457/combining-manipulated-plots), to no avail :(

*This is a slimmed-down version of a previous (deleted) post - I hope it is a little clearer :)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
  GridLines -> {Range@5, Range@5}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 200, 
  Prolog -> 
   Inset@DynamicModule[{x = 11}, 
     Grid[
       Map[Button[ToString@#, x = #, 
          Background -> Dynamic[If[Mod[#, x] == 0, Green, Red]], 
          ImageSize -> {40, 40}, Appearance -> "Frameless"] &, 
        RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 5}], {2}], Frame -> All, 
       FrameStyle -> Dashed, Spacings -> {.2, .2}]]],
 {n, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Manipulate output]

Comment: @ Michael E2, Thank you very much for your help on this - if this was what I was trying to achieve, I would be very happy with your solution, but I am trying to stitch together two longer, more complicated pieces of code (see update). I posted this as the question originally, but was advised to make it shorter ... I am really struggling with this though - pulling my hair out! :/

Comment: @martin You should be aware that the purpose of this site isn't helping you with _your_ application, but with the Mathematica platform. Posting your full code will attract downvotes, cause people to skip reading your questions, you will probably catch dandruff and your fridge will stop working. Seriously, don't do that

Comment: @ belisarius, Point taken - the struggle continues!

Comment: @martin You might consider using `ClickPane[graphics, func]`  instead of `Button`.  You can use `func` to set your variable `x` and change the color of `Rectangles` (like you do the background) in response to mouse clicks.  It's easier to combine graphics than mix graphics and non-graphics.

Comment: @ Michael E2, Great, thanks - I will try that now :)