# Dynamically transform one Graphics to another

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I would like to have two `Graphics` objects displayed side by side such that:

- they are mirror images of each other
- if I change the left-hand one interactively using *Drawing Tools*, the other one is updated automatically.

I can't seem to convince `Dynamic`, `Manipulate` and friends to do this for me. How can I do it?

A more basic question would be: how do I create a variable which holds a `Graphics` object and such that its value can be changed interactively using *Drawing Tools*?

Comment: Assuming you mean Graphics not Graph ... is [Combining manipulated plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13457/combining-manipulated-plots) of any help?

Comment: Did I write "Graph" anywhere by accident?

Comment: No, that question just asks how to have to dynamic `Graphics` objects next to each other. I want one of them to reflect the content of the other, dynamically, so that if I *edit interactively* the one, the other changes.

Comment: I was pointing to the second answer, good luck.

Comment: Well, both answers are useless. Have you read my question?

Comment: I think it is likely that this is impossible. Variables get their values from the kernel, but *Drawing Tools* works entirely in the front end. There isn't any variable that holds the updates that you do to the image.

Comment: Hmm. If I have to give up on the Drawing tools then I could at least make a simple drawing canvas. That would work.

Comment: This can be done if you would accept a button or other manual control to copy from left to right. If you don't want the button then the solution may not be possible unless the second Graphics is in a cell different from the one being modified.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda: oh, button would be great. I've been trying to figure out how to get the content of the graphics from the frontend to the kernel, so if you can show me that, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

This solution may generate a storm of criticisms but may also give you an idea of a path to follow to get where you want.  Note that this solution works perfectly in Mathematica 9 but in Mathematica 10 there is a problem that is preventing the last Graphics object added to copy to the right side with the right colors.

```
    g = Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 200];
rightSide = Style["Left side will be copied here.", Gray, Italic];
Deploy@Panel@
  Grid[{{
     Labeled[Button["Copy to Right Side",
       Block[{cellContents = NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]], rs},
        rs = 
         cellContents[[Sequence @@ 
             Position[cellContents, GridBox[{{_, _}}, ___]][[2]]]][[1,
            1, 1, 1, 2]];
        rightSide = 
         ReplaceAll[DisplayForm@rs, GraphicsBox -> Graphics];
        ]
       , ImageSize -> Automatic
       ], Style[g, Deployed -> False]]
     ,
     Labeled[
      "Copy of Left Side"
      , Dynamic@rightSide
      ]
     }}
   , Alignment -> Left
   ]
```

This is how it looks after the first evaluation:

[image]

And this is how it looks after adding two Graphics elements and pressing the "Copy to Right Side" button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another apporach is to make a Manipulate that does what you want. For example, here is one that draws a polygon. Whenever you move the points of the left polygon, the one on the right moves in mirror symmetry.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Polygon[p], Red, Polygon[ConstantArray[{10, 0}, 4] - p]}], 
   {{p, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {-1, 1}, {-2, -2}}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The main point is that the solution works when Drawing Tools is used.

Comment: Well, I read the OPs comment "If I have to give up on the Drawing tools then I could at least make a simple drawing canvas. That would work" and thought an alternative approach (ie., a "simple drawing canvas") might be useful.

Comment: How could I do this but have *two* `Graphics` objects, so the shapes can't get mixed up? If I place the red object into another `Graphics` and then combine them with `Grid`, I think the locators are screwed up (they are relative to the entire grid, not just the left-hand `Graphics`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, despite Drawing tools only works in FrontEnd, you can always get the CellExpression directly:

```
Grid[{
        {"draw here:", "watch it here:"},
        {Graphics[],
            Dynamic[Refresh[
                    Cases[
                                NotebookRead[
                                    EvaluationCell[]], _GraphicsBox, ∞][[1]] // 
                        RawBoxes,
                    UpdateInterval -> 0]]
            }
        }, Frame -> All]
```