# Grid snap for drawing tools

Tags: palettes, drawing

Is it possible to extend the *Drawing Tools* palette and add a grid snap feature? Drawing points with discrete intervals would make it a *lot easier* to draw nice free body diagrams, and other simple problem sets without needing to page out of *Mathematica*.

[image]

**Image 1**: Typical situation where I page out of *Mathematica* to *Illustrator*. Grid snap makes it much easier and quicker than snapping to elements. Grid that I snap to is shown in the background.

New students are intimidated by learning yet another tool. And frankly I can and do write these in code as well, but students take time to learn to do so.

Comment: Does the Drawing Tools need to be involved? Would be easier with just points and lines.

Comment: @Öskå Maybe, drawing tools would be pretty competent for this particular case if it had snap to grid, when not its a bit painful and useless tool. Idea that these are sketches before any calculation. Preference is NO code it scares the lower 2/3 of students away.

Comment: I'm afraid that the drawing tools can't be incorporated in a piece of code see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57299/dynamically-transform-one-graphics-to-another#comment164267_57299). Thus the easiest would be to create your own drawing tools with basic primitives like line/circle/point. The code would scare them, the GUI might not.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE:**

1. This works on my Mathematica 10, but not tested on other versions.
2. This method involving modification of a system file, **thus is likely prohibited by the EULA**.

---

First locate the notebook corresponding to the Drawing Tools, which should be on a path similar to the following:

> *(Mathematica root)*\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\SystemResources\DrawingTools.nb

Looking for this string:

> "NewGraphicButtonText"

There should be 2 matches, around whom it looks like this:

[image: location of "NewGraphicButtonText"]

Note the selected `""` in the above snapshot, we are going to replace it with the following code:

( **DON'T FORGET TO BACKUP THE ORIGINAL .NB FILE!** )

```
   (* added by silvia v *)

   TagBox[TooltipBox[ ButtonBox[GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData[" 1:eJzVlU0KwjAQhYu68BC68Ch6BF27aEG3QiuIFwl4Ig/gqstSjFUQQRBF/Hsq Dg+sLuIo+EGGdMj7aEva1IJes1vwPC8qozT9QT0M/WGrhIvGsN8JiphUMSoY 1/lYmyzLUBd6iHOpB2zWWtS1HrClaYq60wO2JElQj3qI80xED9rE+ybHXzlH N7g5evDcfOU8EQ5OjovzQOChznkYY3L7WM9xce4JByfHxbklHJwcF+eGcHBy XJwrAmtMHnftM1jPcXHOCIf75Lg4p4SDk+N/7XT4jn7mtITDf4njuXvpQ77q zPQQ51wPceqe73enLnDiJeBEjuN4ogE8sMGJfYVJogE8sF0AMHUuOQ== "], {{0, 29}, {28, 0}}, {0, 255}, ColorFunction -> RGBColor], BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True], Selectable -> False], BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", ImageSizeRaw -> {28, 29}, PlotRange -> {{0, 28}, {0, 29}}], Appearance -> None, ButtonFunction :> FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], GraphicsBox[{GraphicsGroupBox[{GrayLevel[0.9], LineBox[{{-2.`, -2.`}, {-2.`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.98`, -2.`}, {-1.98`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.96`, -2.`}, {-1.96`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.94`, -2.`}, {-1.94`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.92`, -2.`}, {-1.92`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.9`, -2.`}, {-1.9`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.88`, -2.`}, {-1.88`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.86`, -2.`}, {-1.86`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.84`, -2.`}, {-1.84`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.82`, -2.`}, {-1.82`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.8`, -2.`}, {-1.8`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.78`, -2.`}, {-1.78`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.76`, -2.`}, {-1.76`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.74`, -2.`}, {-1.74`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.72`, -2.`}, {-1.72`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.7`, -2.`}, {-1.7`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.68`, -2.`}, {-1.68`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.66`, -2.`}, {-1.66`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.64`, -2.`}, {-1.64`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.62`, -2.`}, {-1.62`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.6`, -2.`}, {-1.6`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.58`, -2.`}, {-1.58`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.56`, -2.`}, {-1.56`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.54`, -2.`}, {-1.54`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.52`, -2.`}, {-1.52`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.5`, -2.`}, {-1.5`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.48`, -2.`}, {-1.48`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.46`, -2.`}, {-1.46`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.44`, -2.`}, {-1.44`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.42`, -2.`}, {-1.42`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.4`, -2.`}, {-1.4`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.38`, -2.`}, {-1.38`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.36`, -2.`}, {-1.36`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.34`, -2.`}, {-1.34`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.32`, -2.`}, {-1.32`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.3`, -2.`}, {-1.3`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.28`, -2.`}, {-1.28`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.26`, -2.`}, {-1.26`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.24`, -2.`}, {-1.24`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.22`, -2.`}, {-1.22`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.2`, -2.`}, {-1.2`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.18`, -2.`}, {-1.18`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.16`, -2.`}, {-1.16`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.14`, -2.`}, {-1.14`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.12`, -2.`}, {-1.12`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.1`, -2.`}, {-1.1`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.08`, -2.`}, {-1.08`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.06`, -2.`}, {-1.06`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.04`, -2.`}, {-1.04`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.02`, -2.`}, {-1.02`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-1.`, -2.`}, {-1.`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.98`, -2.`}, {-0.98`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.96`, -2.`}, {-0.96`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.94`, -2.`}, {-0.94`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.92`, -2.`}, {-0.92`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.9`, -2.`}, {-0.9`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.88`, -2.`}, {-0.88`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.86`, -2.`}, {-0.86`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.84`, -2.`}, {-0.84`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.82`, -2.`}, {-0.82`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.8`, -2.`}, {-0.8`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.78`, -2.`}, {-0.78`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.76`, -2.`}, {-0.76`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.74`, -2.`}, {-0.74`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.72`, -2.`}, {-0.72`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.7`, -2.`}, {-0.7`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.68`, -2.`}, {-0.68`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.66`, -2.`}, {-0.66`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.64`, -2.`}, {-0.64`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.62`, -2.`}, {-0.62`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.6`, -2.`}, {-0.6`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.58`, -2.`}, {-0.58`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.56`, -2.`}, {-0.56`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.54`, -2.`}, {-0.54`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.52`, -2.`}, {-0.52`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.5`, -2.`}, {-0.5`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.48`, -2.`}, {-0.48`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.46`, -2.`}, {-0.46`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.44`, -2.`}, {-0.44`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.42`, -2.`}, {-0.42`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.4`, -2.`}, {-0.4`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.38`, -2.`}, {-0.38`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.36`, -2.`}, {-0.36`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.34`, -2.`}, {-0.34`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.32`, -2.`}, {-0.32`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.3`, -2.`}, {-0.3`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.28`, -2.`}, {-0.28`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.26`, -2.`}, {-0.26`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.24`, -2.`}, {-0.24`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.22`, -2.`}, {-0.22`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.2`, -2.`}, {-0.2`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.18`, -2.`}, {-0.18`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.16`, -2.`}, {-0.16`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.14`, -2.`}, {-0.14`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.12`, -2.`}, {-0.12`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.1`, -2.`}, {-0.1`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.08`, -2.`}, {-0.08`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.06`, -2.`}, {-0.06`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.04`, -2.`}, {-0.04`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-0.02`, -2.`}, {-0.02`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.`, -2.`}, {0.`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.02`, -2.`}, {0.02`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.04`, -2.`}, {0.04`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.06`, -2.`}, {0.06`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.08`, -2.`}, {0.08`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.1`, -2.`}, {0.1`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.12`, -2.`}, {0.12`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.14`, -2.`}, {0.14`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.16`, -2.`}, {0.16`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.18`, -2.`}, {0.18`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.2`, -2.`}, {0.2`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.22`, -2.`}, {0.22`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.24`, -2.`}, {0.24`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.26`, -2.`}, {0.26`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.28`, -2.`}, {0.28`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.3`, -2.`}, {0.3`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.32`, -2.`}, {0.32`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.34`, -2.`}, {0.34`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.36`, -2.`}, {0.36`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.38`, -2.`}, {0.38`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.4`, -2.`}, {0.4`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.42`, -2.`}, {0.42`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.44`, -2.`}, {0.44`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.46`, -2.`}, {0.46`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.48`, -2.`}, {0.48`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.5`, -2.`}, {0.5`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.52`, -2.`}, {0.52`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.54`, -2.`}, {0.54`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.56`, -2.`}, {0.56`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.58`, -2.`}, {0.58`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.6`, -2.`}, {0.6`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.62`, -2.`}, {0.62`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.64`, -2.`}, {0.64`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.66`, -2.`}, {0.66`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.68`, -2.`}, {0.68`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.7`, -2.`}, {0.7`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.72`, -2.`}, {0.72`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.74`, -2.`}, {0.74`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.76`, -2.`}, {0.76`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.78`, -2.`}, {0.78`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.8`, -2.`}, {0.8`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.82`, -2.`}, {0.82`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.84`, -2.`}, {0.84`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.86`, -2.`}, {0.86`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.88`, -2.`}, {0.88`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.9`, -2.`}, {0.9`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.92`, -2.`}, {0.92`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.94`, -2.`}, {0.94`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.96`, -2.`}, {0.96`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{0.98`, -2.`}, {0.98`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.`, -2.`}, {1.`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.02`, -2.`}, {1.02`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.04`, -2.`}, {1.04`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.06`, -2.`}, {1.06`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.08`, -2.`}, {1.08`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.1`, -2.`}, {1.1`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.12`, -2.`}, {1.12`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.14`, -2.`}, {1.14`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.16`, -2.`}, {1.16`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.18`, -2.`}, {1.18`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.2`, -2.`}, {1.2`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.22`, -2.`}, {1.22`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.24`, -2.`}, {1.24`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.26`, -2.`}, {1.26`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.28`, -2.`}, {1.28`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.3`, -2.`}, {1.3`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.32`, -2.`}, {1.32`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.34`, -2.`}, {1.34`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.36`, -2.`}, {1.36`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.38`, -2.`}, {1.38`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.4`, -2.`}, {1.4`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.42`, -2.`}, {1.42`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.44`, -2.`}, {1.44`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.46`, -2.`}, {1.46`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.48`, -2.`}, {1.48`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.5`, -2.`}, {1.5`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.52`, -2.`}, {1.52`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.54`, -2.`}, {1.54`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.56`, -2.`}, {1.56`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.58`, -2.`}, {1.58`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.6`, -2.`}, {1.6`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.62`, -2.`}, {1.62`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.64`, -2.`}, {1.64`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.66`, -2.`}, {1.66`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.68`, -2.`}, {1.68`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.7`, -2.`}, {1.7`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.72`, -2.`}, {1.72`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.74`, -2.`}, {1.74`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.76`, -2.`}, {1.76`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.78`, -2.`}, {1.78`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.8`, -2.`}, {1.8`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.82`, -2.`}, {1.82`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.84`, -2.`}, {1.84`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.86`, -2.`}, {1.86`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.88`, -2.`}, {1.88`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.9`, -2.`}, {1.9`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.92`, -2.`}, {1.92`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.94`, -2.`}, {1.94`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.96`, -2.`}, {1.96`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{1.98`, -2.`}, {1.98`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{2.`, -2.`}, {2.`, 2.`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -2.`}, {2.`, -2.`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.98`}, {2.`, -1.98`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.96`}, {2.`, -1.96`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.94`}, {2.`, -1.94`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.92`}, {2.`, -1.92`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.9`}, {2.`, -1.9`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.88`}, {2.`, -1.88`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.86`}, {2.`, -1.86`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.84`}, {2.`, -1.84`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.82`}, {2.`, -1.82`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.8`}, {2.`, -1.8`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.78`}, {2.`, -1.78`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.76`}, {2.`, -1.76`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.74`}, {2.`, -1.74`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.72`}, {2.`, -1.72`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.7`}, {2.`, -1.7`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.68`}, {2.`, -1.68`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.66`}, {2.`, -1.66`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.64`}, {2.`, -1.64`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.62`}, {2.`, -1.62`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.6`}, {2.`, -1.6`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.58`}, {2.`, -1.58`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.56`}, {2.`, -1.56`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.54`}, {2.`, -1.54`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.52`}, {2.`, -1.52`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.5`}, {2.`, -1.5`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.48`}, {2.`, -1.48`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.46`}, {2.`, -1.46`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.44`}, {2.`, -1.44`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.42`}, {2.`, -1.42`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.4`}, {2.`, -1.4`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.38`}, {2.`, -1.38`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.36`}, {2.`, -1.36`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.34`}, {2.`, -1.34`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.32`}, {2.`, -1.32`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.3`}, {2.`, -1.3`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.28`}, {2.`, -1.28`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.26`}, {2.`, -1.26`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.24`}, {2.`, -1.24`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.22`}, {2.`, -1.22`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.2`}, {2.`, -1.2`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.18`}, {2.`, -1.18`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.16`}, {2.`, -1.16`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.14`}, {2.`, -1.14`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.12`}, {2.`, -1.12`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.1`}, {2.`, -1.1`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.08`}, {2.`, -1.08`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.06`}, {2.`, -1.06`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.04`}, {2.`, -1.04`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.02`}, {2.`, -1.02`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -1.`}, {2.`, -1.`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.98`}, {2.`, -0.98`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.96`}, {2.`, -0.96`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.94`}, {2.`, -0.94`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.92`}, {2.`, -0.92`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.9`}, {2.`, -0.9`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.88`}, {2.`, -0.88`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.86`}, {2.`, -0.86`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.84`}, {2.`, -0.84`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.82`}, {2.`, -0.82`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.8`}, {2.`, -0.8`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.78`}, {2.`, -0.78`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.76`}, {2.`, -0.76`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.74`}, {2.`, -0.74`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.72`}, {2.`, -0.72`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.7`}, {2.`, -0.7`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.68`}, {2.`, -0.68`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.66`}, {2.`, -0.66`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.64`}, {2.`, -0.64`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.62`}, {2.`, -0.62`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.6`}, {2.`, -0.6`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.58`}, {2.`, -0.58`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.56`}, {2.`, -0.56`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.54`}, {2.`, -0.54`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.52`}, {2.`, -0.52`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.5`}, {2.`, -0.5`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.48`}, {2.`, -0.48`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.46`}, {2.`, -0.46`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.44`}, {2.`, -0.44`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.42`}, {2.`, -0.42`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.4`}, {2.`, -0.4`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.38`}, {2.`, -0.38`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.36`}, {2.`, -0.36`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.34`}, {2.`, -0.34`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.32`}, {2.`, -0.32`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.3`}, {2.`, -0.3`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.28`}, {2.`, -0.28`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.26`}, {2.`, -0.26`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.24`}, {2.`, -0.24`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.22`}, {2.`, -0.22`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.2`}, {2.`, -0.2`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.18`}, {2.`, -0.18`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.16`}, {2.`, -0.16`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.14`}, {2.`, -0.14`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.12`}, {2.`, -0.12`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.1`}, {2.`, -0.1`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.08`}, {2.`, -0.08`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.06`}, {2.`, -0.06`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.04`}, {2.`, -0.04`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, -0.02`}, {2.`, -0.02`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.`}, {2.`, 0.`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.02`}, {2.`, 0.02`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.04`}, {2.`, 0.04`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.06`}, {2.`, 0.06`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.08`}, {2.`, 0.08`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.1`}, {2.`, 0.1`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.12`}, {2.`, 0.12`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.14`}, {2.`, 0.14`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.16`}, {2.`, 0.16`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.18`}, {2.`, 0.18`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.2`}, {2.`, 0.2`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.22`}, {2.`, 0.22`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.24`}, {2.`, 0.24`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.26`}, {2.`, 0.26`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.28`}, {2.`, 0.28`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.3`}, {2.`, 0.3`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.32`}, {2.`, 0.32`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.34`}, {2.`, 0.34`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.36`}, {2.`, 0.36`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.38`}, {2.`, 0.38`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.4`}, {2.`, 0.4`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.42`}, {2.`, 0.42`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.44`}, {2.`, 0.44`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.46`}, {2.`, 0.46`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.48`}, {2.`, 0.48`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.5`}, {2.`, 0.5`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.52`}, {2.`, 0.52`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.54`}, {2.`, 0.54`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.56`}, {2.`, 0.56`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.58`}, {2.`, 0.58`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.6`}, {2.`, 0.6`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.62`}, {2.`, 0.62`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.64`}, {2.`, 0.64`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.66`}, {2.`, 0.66`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.68`}, {2.`, 0.68`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.7`}, {2.`, 0.7`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.72`}, {2.`, 0.72`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.74`}, {2.`, 0.74`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.76`}, {2.`, 0.76`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.78`}, {2.`, 0.78`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.8`}, {2.`, 0.8`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.82`}, {2.`, 0.82`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.84`}, {2.`, 0.84`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.86`}, {2.`, 0.86`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.88`}, {2.`, 0.88`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.9`}, {2.`, 0.9`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.92`}, {2.`, 0.92`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.94`}, {2.`, 0.94`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.96`}, {2.`, 0.96`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 0.98`}, {2.`, 0.98`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.`}, {2.`, 1.`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.02`}, {2.`, 1.02`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.04`}, {2.`, 1.04`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.06`}, {2.`, 1.06`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.08`}, {2.`, 1.08`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.1`}, {2.`, 1.1`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.12`}, {2.`, 1.12`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.14`}, {2.`, 1.14`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.16`}, {2.`, 1.16`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.18`}, {2.`, 1.18`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.2`}, {2.`, 1.2`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.22`}, {2.`, 1.22`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.24`}, {2.`, 1.24`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.26`}, {2.`, 1.26`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.28`}, {2.`, 1.28`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.3`}, {2.`, 1.3`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.32`}, {2.`, 1.32`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.34`}, {2.`, 1.34`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.36`}, {2.`, 1.36`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.38`}, {2.`, 1.38`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.4`}, {2.`, 1.4`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.42`}, {2.`, 1.42`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.44`}, {2.`, 1.44`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.46`}, {2.`, 1.46`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.48`}, {2.`, 1.48`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.5`}, {2.`, 1.5`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.52`}, {2.`, 1.52`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.54`}, {2.`, 1.54`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.56`}, {2.`, 1.56`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.58`}, {2.`, 1.58`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.6`}, {2.`, 1.6`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.62`}, {2.`, 1.62`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.64`}, {2.`, 1.64`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.66`}, {2.`, 1.66`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.68`}, {2.`, 1.68`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.7`}, {2.`, 1.7`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.72`}, {2.`, 1.72`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.74`}, {2.`, 1.74`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.76`}, {2.`, 1.76`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.78`}, {2.`, 1.78`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.8`}, {2.`, 1.8`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.82`}, {2.`, 1.82`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.84`}, {2.`, 1.84`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.86`}, {2.`, 1.86`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.88`}, {2.`, 1.88`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.9`}, {2.`, 1.9`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.92`}, {2.`, 1.92`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.94`}, {2.`, 1.94`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.96`}, {2.`, 1.96`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 1.98`}, {2.`, 1.98`}}], LineBox[{{-2.`, 2.`}, {2.`, 2.`}}]}, ContentSelectable -> False]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> {480, 480}, ContentSelectable -> True], After], FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], Previous, "Graphics"]}], Evaluator -> None, Method -> "Preemptive"], "New Graphics (with guide\[Hyphen]grid)"], Annotation[#, "New Graphics (with guide\[Hyphen]grid)", "Tooltip"] &]

   (* added by silvia ^ *)
```

Save the file and reopen the Drawing Tools palette in Mathematica (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), you should see a new button at the right side of the old "New Graphics" button:

[image: new Drawing Tools palette]

Press it (and don't forget to switch on the "Toggle Alignment Guides"), you should see a canvas with guide-grids:

[image: canvas with guide grids]

Comment: I would still like foced quantize move instead of a shown grid that i can snap to its mentally faster

Comment: @joojaa Forcing a quantized move would be much harder if insist sticking with the built-in Drawing Tools, as a large part of its operating principle is unknown to the end users, which makes any further hacking very hard, if not impossible.

Comment: I dont dispute that. Im still saying this is not perfect even if its VERY useful. TY

Comment: @joojaa You're welcome! And maybe someone else will come up with a better solution. Don't feel hesitated to change the acceptance!